# Why google place api integration not worked

Tags: javascript, json, google-places-api

json data while follow the given link but it is worked when I integrate in our project.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyCaLjRTWe0j9RKu9qG4_9VovLltLtU_hQ8

[image]

[image: error while integrate in project]

Comment: Have you tried googling "cross origin policy" or "CORS" (or anything else from the error message in your picture)?

Answer (score 0):

Servers can enable CORS, meaning that they will accept requests from other domains. However, each server is different and most APIs still do not allow cross-origin requests. It looks like api.geonames.org is one of these that does not support CORS.

Note that CORS only applies to requests sent from a browser. Hitting that API from a backend server (like Node or Rails) will work just fine.